# type mismatch when running Access.Application.DoCmd through Powershell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, ms-access, com

I'm having an issue with my code. I am hoping to use PowerShell to open an Access file, then export a table to an Excel file. so far, this is my code.

```
$MsAccess = New-object -com Access.Application
$MsAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase('<Filepath>',$false)
$MsAccess.Application.DoCmd.OpenTable("<TableName>")
$MsAccess.Application.DoCmd.OutputTo('acOutputTable, "<TableName>" , acFormatXLS , "OutputName.xls", true')
$MsAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase()
$MsAccess.Quit()
```

It will always error at:

```
$MsAccess.Application.DoCmd.OutputTo('acOutputTable, "TableName" , acFormatXLS , "OutputName.xls", true')
```

with an error stating:

```
 $MsAccess.Application.DoCmd.OutputTo('acOutputTable, "TableName" , acFormatXLS , "OutputName.xls", true')
Exception calling "OutputTo" with "1" argument(s): "Type mismatch. (Exception 
from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"
```

I have been attempting to export a table to excel for a bit of time, but i cant seem to find much documentation about using excel through PowerShell. Would anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

```
note: placeholders such as TableName, filepath, etc are not actual names, just replacements
```

Comment: Looks like you are passing your arguments as just one string. Rather than an array of multiple elements. Does this work?`$MsAccess.Application.DoCmd.OutputTo("acOutputTable", "TableName" , acFormatXLS , "OutputName.xls", "true")`

Comment: @BenH I just tried that, but it seems to be having the same issue with a data mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$MsAccess.Application.DoCmd.OutputTo(0, "<TableName>" , 0, "OutputName.xls", $true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the docmd.transfer spreadsheet command in order to resolve this issue. I guess powershell doesn't like outputto.